# Triggering angular directive from capybara/poltergeist feature test

Tags: javascript, ruby, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara

Capybara + Poltergeist are working fine for most of my feature tests in a rails 4 + angular app. However, I have problems testing code that uses the [danielfard--angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) JS library. My file upload code relies on a directive in that library called `ngFileSelect` [(source for the directive here)](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload/blob/master/dist/angular-file-upload.js#L134). This works perfectly when I click through the process in the browser, but I can't get it to fire in my feature tests.

My angular-ified HAML:

```
%input{ng: {"file-select" => "onFileSelect($files)"}, type: "file", multiple: true, id: "img-file-select"}
```

I tried using Capybara's `attach_file` method. This doesn't file but by watching the DB I can tell no upload is happening.

```
#does not fail but does not trigger upload
attach_file "img-file-select", 
  ["#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/images/property.jpg",
  "#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/images/kitchen.jpg"]
```

I also tried using the `trigger` method to fire events manually. These do fail.

```
#these fail with with 'Capybara::Poltergeist::BrowserError: Unknown event [object Object]'
find("#img-file-select").trigger('ngFileSelect')
find("#img-file-select").trigger('fileSelect')
find("#img-file-select").trigger('change')
```

Is there some way of firing this directive from a capybara test?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do:

```
page.execute_script <<-JS
  fakeFileInput = window.$('<input/>').attr({ id: 'fileFileInput', type: 'file' }).appendTo('body');
JS

page.attach_file('fakeFileInput', Rails.root.join('spec', 'fixtures', 'images', 'property.jpg'))

page.execute_script <<-JS
  var scope = angular.element('#img-file-select').scope();
  scope.files = [fakeFileInput.get(0).files[0]];
JS
```

Answer (score 0):

Capybara provides a way of executing arbitrary javascript.

```
page.evaluate_script('4 + 4');
```

Take a look [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#scripting), but you should be able to fire whatever javascript event you need by using this method.